# json not loads data properly

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to snip a embedded json from a webpage and then passing the json object to `json.loads()`. First url is okay but when loading the second url it's return error

> ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 2078 (char 2077)

here is the code

```
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://www.autotrader.co.uk/dealers/greater-manchester/manchester/williams-landrover-9994',
'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/dealers/warwickshire/stratford-upon-avon/guy-salmon-land-rover-stratford-upon-avon-9965'
]

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')[0]
    data = scripts.text.split("window['AT_APOLLO_STATE'] = ")[1].split(';')[0]
    jdata = json.loads(data)
    print(jdata)
```

Comment: add `print(data)` before `json.loads` so you can see the output of the scraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print out `scripts.text.split("window['AT_APOLLO_STATE'] = ")[1]`, you will see the follows that includes a `;` right after `and enthusiastic`. So you get an invalid json string from `scripts.text.split("window['AT_APOLLO_STATE'] = ")[1].split(';')[0]`. And the data ends with `and enthusiastic` that is not a valid `json` string.

`"strapline":"In our state-of-the-art dealerships across the U.K, Sytner Group 
represents the world’s most prestigious car manufacturers. 
All of our staff are knowledgeable and enthusiastic; making every interaction 
special by going the extra mile.",`

Answer (score 1):

Reason has been given. You could also regex out appropriate string

```
import requests,json

urls = ['https://www.autotrader.co.uk/dealers/greater-manchester/manchester/williams-landrover-9994',
'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/dealers/warwickshire/stratford-upon-avon/guy-salmon-land-rover-stratford-upon-avon-9965'
]

p = re.compile(r"window\['AT_APOLLO_STATE'\] =(.*?});", re.DOTALL)
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    jdata = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
    print(jdata)
```

Missed a `}` in the original post.